# Python docker / detectem not working

Tags: python, docker

I installed Docker CE using the recommended way
and then installed detectem following the procedure on https://pypi.python.org/pypi/detectem/0.1.3
Everything seems to work properly, Docker seems to work and detectem is installed successfully. I am also working in a virtual environment as recommended. However, the typical detectem command is not working, typing in the console

```
det http://example.webscraping.com/
```

I get several exception errors:

> PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
>   requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', PermissionError(13, 'Permission denied'))
>   requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', PermissionError(13, 'Permission denied'))

Does anybody have a clue what's going wrong here?

Comment: How was Docker installed? What s the host OS? What is the full traceback? What Docker version? What Python version?

Comment: Recebnt Docker installed using the recommended repository procedure on https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/#install-using-the-repository. It'S Docker CE x86_64 and Python 3.52

Comment: Can you include your Dockerfile? There is a lot of contextual information that is missing here. please include enough information that someone could reliably reproduce your issue in their own environment.